# Remove coloured background scanned PDF (original document printed on coloured paper)

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Someone has sent me a scanned document, which they have printed out on pink paper prior to scanning.

Ive taken the scanned document into Acrobat DC (pro, latest version as of time of writing) and run the enhance scan function on it, to clean up the scan and to OCR the text, but the pink background still remains.

Ive tried some colour conversion options, but this seems to make the pink background grey. How can i remove the pink background leaving a white background instead ?

Comment: Do you have access to Photoshop?

Comment: Is the print itself monochrome?  Also, could you post a small example as it might help us to help you. Pink could be anything from a vibrant to a pastel shade. Can you please edit your question and provide more details. Thanks.

Comment: @Wolff i do, my first knee jerk reaction was to put the document into photoshop and using the levels function set the pink as the white point, my concern is that a long multi page PDF so wondered if it could be done in more of an automated fashion using acrobat.

Comment: @BillyKerr Unfortunately i cant publish / share the document.

Comment: I'm not sure, but i don't think Acrobat has that many options. I use a plugin called Enfocus Pitstop Pro for Acrobat which enables me to do many automatized tasks on whole documents. If I didn't have that, I would make a Photoshop action and start to chew my way through the pages one at a time. How many pages are there? Sometimes your time is better spend trying to obtain the original document digitally. Regarding screenshot: Isn't it possible to find a small sample which isn't too revealing?

Answer (score 1):

You have Acrobat, the full one? Then you reprint the document as new PDF, but as CMYK color separated. Hopefully all interesting is in K-plate. Make a PDF of it.

Another option: You wrote the texts are optically recognized. Then you can copy and paste them as plain text data, not as text objects, to any writing program and assemble there a new properly laid version.